# Insert string while looping through element ids

Tags: javascript, html

I have this Javascript function which writes to the console all the textContent found within table cells:

```
function checkoutSystem() {  
    var table = document.getElementById('checkOutTable');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            results=table.rows[r].cells[c].textContent;
            console.log(results);
        }
    }
}
```

The console then shows these results when running the function:

```
"LG D2343P-BN 23-inch"
"1 X"
"99.99"
"Ethernet Cable 50m Cat 5e"
"1 X"
"24.99"
"Total"
"124.98"
"Empty Cart"
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
"orderTitle=LG D2343P-BN 23-inch"
"orderQty=1"
"orderPrice=24.99"
"orderTotal=124.98"
```

I don't want the javascript to get the X in "1 X" nor do I want it to show "Empty Cart" or "Total" I then want to post the values using AJAX. This is an assignment, I am not aloud to use jQuery :/

```
http.open("POST", url, true);
```

Here is the HTML Table:

```
<table id="checkOutTable" class="checkOut">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">LG D2343P-BN 23-inch</td>
            <td align="center">1 
                <a href="/637415/cms/pages/cart.php?action=remove&amp;id=46\">X</a>
            </td>
            <td align="center">99.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">Ethernet Cable 50m Cat 5e</td>
            <td align="center">1 
                <a href="/637415/cms/pages/cart.php?action=remove&amp;id=38\">X</a>
            </td>
            <td align="center">24.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="padding-right: 10px;" align="right">Total</td>
            <td align="right">124.98</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td colspan="3" align="right">
                <a href="/637415/cms/pages/cart.php?action=empty" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Empty Cart</a>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of labels that match the cell indexes:

```
var labels = ['orderTitle','orderQty','orderPrice','orderTotal'];
```

and also if the index is 1, use parseInt on the content. So:

```
value = table.rows[r].cells[c].textContent;
results = labels[c] + '=' + c == 1? parseInt(value) : value;
```

and for the last row, only iterate over rows.length - 1 and do the last row outside the loop:

```
for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length - 1; r < n; r++) {
  // ...
}
results = labels[++c] + '=' + parseInt(table.rows[r].cells[1].textContent, 10);
```

Note that in the last statement, *r* is incremented to `length - 1` before the loop skips the block, so it is set to the index of the last row. And since the inner for loop hasn't restarted, *c* is still set to the last index (2), hence `++c` will set it 3 and you'll get the last label.

I assume that sending *results* to the console is just for development and that in reality you'll collect the values in an array or object, then build whatever you need to send the data to server.

#### Edit

Sorry, I hate JSFIDDLE. If you want to paste updated code, just paste it here as an edit to your question. There were a couple if issues with the code, I didn't realise the empty cart button was in a separate row or that there was a colspan attribute on the totals row. The following "works":

```
function checkoutSystem() {
  var table = document.getElementById('checkOutTable');
  var labels = ['orderTitle','orderQty','orderPrice','orderTotal'];
  var results = [];

  // Note length - 2
  for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length - 2; r < n; r++) {

    for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
      value = table.rows[r].cells[c].textContent;
      results.push(labels[c] + '=' + (c == 1? parseInt(value, 10) : value));
    }
  }
  results.push(labels[c] + '=' + parseFloat(table.rows[r].cells[1].textContent));

  console.log(results.join('\n'));

}
```

I've added a radix to *parseInt* which probably is unnecessary but just in case.

Note that *textContent* will not work in IE 8 or lower. You can use a *getText* function like the following instead:

```
function getText(element) {
  if (typeof element.textContent == 'string') {
    return element.textContent;
  } else if (typeof element.innerText == 'string') {
    return element.innerText;
  }
}
```

and use it like:

```
value = getText(table.rows[r].cells[c]);
```

The function can probably be reduced to:

```
function getText(element) {
  return element.textContent || element.innerText || '';
}
```

but I prefer the first. You can also add another *else* for browsers that don't support either *textContent* or *innerText* that iterates over all child nodes and concatenates the contents of text nodes, but that isn't necessary unless you're dealing with ancient browsers or user agents.

Oh, and I'd move the onload listener to the body element as even though HTML5 says it should supported by all elements, it isn't in all (any?) browser. If you really need to reliably run the code just after the table loads, put it in a script element just after the closing table tag.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I am getting a undefined in the console window. Is this how the code is suppose to look?: [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hhN92/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed  your code  as below

```
    function Item(orderTitle, orderQty, orderPrice) {
        this.orderTitle = orderTitle;
        this.orderQty = Number.parseFloat(orderQty);
        this.orderPrice = Number.parseFloat(orderPrice);
    };

    function Order() {
        this.items = [];
        this.addItem = function (row) {
            var itm = new Item(row.cells[0].textContent,
                               row.cells[1].textContent,
                               row.cells[2].textContent)
            this.items.push(itm);
        };

        this.totalPricae = function () {
            var res = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
                res += (this.items[i].orderQty * this.items[i].orderPrice);
            }
            return Math.round(res* 100 )/ 100;
        };
    };

    function AJAXcall(data) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("Get", "Handler.ashx?data=" + JSON.stringify(data.items), true);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                // you must write your ajax call result to the responce
                //on code behind of your handler.ashx  in context.responce if needed
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }                
        };
    };

    function checkoutSystem() {
        var table = document.getElementById('checkOutTable');
        var newOrder = new Order();
        for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length - 2; r < n; r++) {
            newOrder.addItem(table.rows[r]);
        }
        AJAXcall(newOrder);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your function to the following

`<script type="text/javascript">`

`function checkoutSystem() {`

`var table = document.getElementById('checkOutTable');`

`var labels = ['orderTitle','orderQty','orderPrice','orderTotal'];`

`for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length - 2; r < n; r++) {`

`for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {`

`value = table.rows[r].cells[c].textContent;`

`if (c==1)`

`{ results += labels[c]+' = '+parseInt(value); }`

`else`

`{ results += labels[c]+' = '+value; }`

`}`

`}`

`results += labels[c] + '=' + table.rows[r].cells[1].textContent;`

`console.log(results);`

`}`

`</script>`

Comment: Answers like "just do this" aren't helpful. An answer should explain the error and how to fix it, then offer sample code. If you are offering an improvement on a previous answer, say so and reference the other answer.